# Xubuntu 18.04 -> 18.04.1 Upgrade Synaptics Touchpad Not Working

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

This is my first post here and I have spent many hours trying to read through the posts to diagnose this problem. I used Linux off and on since the late 90s and only recently came back to it.

I was running Xubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad 11e with no issues until I did a ‘sudo apt dist-upgrade‘, which brought me to 18.04.1 (according to lsb_release -a) and my Synaptics s3203_ver5 touchpad stopped working.

Prior to the upgrade my touchpad was working fine, so I know it is compatible with Xubuntu. I tried doing a clean install with 18.04 and the touchpad works until upgrade and dist-upgrade. The last packages I noticed to be updated were kmod and libkmod2.

When I do the following, the touchpad works for 10-20 seconds and then it stops:
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse

Both the following packages are installed:
xserver-xorg-input-libinput 0.27.1-1
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics 1.9.0-1ubuntu1

I tried booting to other kernels 4.15.0-20 and 4.15.0-29 from 4.15.0-38, but that has no effect.

I am a huge fan of Linux and want to stick with it, but I don’t have the time to spend troubleshooting touchpad problems after a system software update. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: This might be related to the kmod issue:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kmod/+bug/1802135

Comment: For those that already installed the kmod version (24-1ubuntu3.1) that caused the failure of the touchpad, I was also able to get it working by going to Software Updater > Developer Options, enabling 'Pre-release updates (bionic-proposed)', and installing the kmod version 24-1ubuntu3.2.  However, you will need to `sudo update-initramfs` for the change to take place.

Answer (score 0):

I referred to your question in resolving my own [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092985/synaptics-touchpad-detected-but-unresponsive-ubuntu-18-04-1-lenovo-yoga-11e).

My solution was to `sudo apt-mark hold kmod` after a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, *then* upgrade to 18.04.1.

I haven't tested it, but reverting `kmod` to version `24-1ubuntu3` from `24-1ubuntu3.1` and `hold`ing it there may have the same result (without starting your system over from scratch like I did).

Comment: Hi Logicisms. I appreciate the response. I just downloaded the Xubuntu 18.04.1 ISO and performed a fresh install. I did as you suggested with `sudo apt-mark hold kmod` (holding 24-1ubuntu3), performed `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, and rebooted. All worked perfectly. Thanks so much for the suggestion!