# Synaptics touchpad detected but unresponsive - Ubuntu 18.04.1, Lenovo Yoga 11e

Tags: gnome, 18.04, touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

> **Caveat:**  I'm far from an advanced user. I like Ubuntu for web development and casual use, and generally try to figure things out as the need arises.

After running a routine update (`apt update`, `apt upgrade`) and later restarting my ThinkPad Yoga 11e (3rd generation, I believe), my touchpad has stopped working completely. It's listed when I run `xinput list`, but nothing I've tried so far has managed to restore functionality.

The touchscreen and keyboard still work as expected, and I haven't had a chance yet to test it with Ubuntu booted from a USB stick. **--Edit 1:** after booting from a USB stick, it appears `xinput` is showing the wrong device for my touchpad.

**Context:** at the time it stopped working, I was running 18.04.1 with Unity (`ubuntu-unity-desktop`), LightDM, and `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. Thinking that Unity and the synaptics driver might have something to do with it, and not getting any helpful search results with so many key phrases, I uninstalled them. Currently running with GNOME, GDM, and `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`.

**--Edit 2:** reinstalled Ubuntu and the touchpad worked, then updated and it's back to being completely unresponsive. Prior to updating, `xinput list` properly showed "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"; after updating, it once again shows "Synaptics s3203_ver5".

**--Edit 3:** wiped the drive and reinstalled 16.04. Same results: touchpad worked after installation, failed after updating. Same `xinput list` results. Reinstalled 18.04 again to start over, and ruled out the kernel as the problem.

**Specs:**
Ubuntu 18.04.1
GNOME 3.28.2
Kernel 4.15.0-39-generic
Synaptics s3203_ver5 **--Edit 1:** should be SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my issue was related to [this kmod bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kmod/+bug/1802135), as cited [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091044/xubuntu-18-04-18-04-1-upgrade-synaptics-touchpad-not-working). Resolved it by preventing `kmod` from updating on a fresh 18.04 install.

After installing 18.04 from a live USB, I ran `sudo apt-mark hold kmod` to lock my `kmod` to version 24, as included in the freshly installed OS. After that, `apt update` and `apt install` ran as expected, my touchpad still works, and `xinput list` returns "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" as expected.

Answer (score 1):

After recent update in 18.04.1 I also start to have issues with not working touchpad and changing brightness with keyboard, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286516/how-do-i-get-the-brightness-control-working-on-a-lenovo-yoga-13) solution for old version of ubuntu fixed it.

To be short, need to add `blacklist ideapad_laptop` in your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding to your grub file

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT "psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0"
```

It worked for me (Thinkpad T440s with updated 3-buttons Trackpad).