# How can I get my trackpad mouse to work again on Thinkpad 11e?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, thinkpad

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 from the USB live image onto the Lenovo Thinkpad 11e and everything worked initially.

After installing the large number of initial undates, the trackpad stopped working at all.

(I didn't notice initially as I had a logitech wireless mouse also, which worked well.)

kernel version is 4.15.0.43

grub offers only 1 one other kernel 4.15.0.29 and trackpad doesnt work there either.

reading another older question relating to 16.04, I tried the commands:

sudo rmmod psmouse

sudo modprobe psmouse

This results in the trackpad working breifly (10-20 seconds only)

Where should I look?
What other info would you like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found similar issue on same hardware with Xubuntu 18.04.1 ([Xubuntu 18.04 -> 18.04.1 Upgrade Synaptics Touchpad Not Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091044/xubuntu-18-04-18-04-1-upgrade-synaptics-touchpad-not-working) )

I checked the kmod package version history (sudo apt-get policy kmod), then downgraded it to the previous version (sudo apt-get install kmod=24-1ubuntu3 libkmod2=24-1ubuntu3) and re-created the initramfs images (sudo update-initramfs -k all -c), then rebooted the laptop. Trackpad works again!

```
paul@paul-ThinkPad-11e:~$ apt-cache policy kmod
kmod:
  Installed: 24-1ubuntu3.1
  Candidate: 24-1ubuntu3.1
  Version table:
 *** 24-1ubuntu3.1 500
        500 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     24-1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

paul@paul-ThinkPad-11e:~$ sudo apt-get install kmod=24-1ubuntu3

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kmod : Depends: libkmod2 (= 24-1ubuntu3) but 24-1ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

paul@paul-ThinkPad-11e:~$ sudo apt-get install kmod=24-1ubuntu3 libkmod2=24-1ubuntu3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  kmod libkmod2
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 downgraded, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
Need to get 129 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 kmod amd64 24-1ubuntu3 [88.6 kB]
Get:2 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libkmod2 amd64 24-1ubuntu3 [40.1 kB]
Fetched 129 kB in 1s (194 kB/s)
dpkg: warning: downgrading kmod from 24-1ubuntu3.1 to 24-1ubuntu3
(Reading database ... 162359 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kmod_24-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kmod (24-1ubuntu3) over (24-1ubuntu3.1) ...
dpkg: warning: downgrading libkmod2:amd64 from 24-1ubuntu3.1 to 24-1ubuntu3
Preparing to unpack .../libkmod2_24-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkmod2:amd64 (24-1ubuntu3) over (24-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up libkmod2:amd64 (24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.11) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up kmod (24-1ubuntu3) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf ...

paul@paul-ThinkPad-11e:~$ sudo update-initramfs -k all -c
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
paul@paul-ThinkPad-11e:~$
```